# C++ - Function declaration error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm having trouble finding the syntax issue with these declarations. Whenever I try to compile, I get this message:

```
generator.cpp:383:46: error: expected unqualified-id before \u2018{\u2019 token
 void assign(Expression *expr, Register *reg) {
                                              ^
```

I'm aware the register keyword exists in C++, but using the otherwise defined Register type works everywhere else in my code; it's just in function declarations where it's putting up the error. I was given these functions as part of the assignment.

```
# include <cassert>
# include <iostream>
# include <typeinfo>
# include <map>
# include <iterator>
# include "generator.h"
# include "Register.h"
# include "machine.h"
# include "Tree.h"
# include "label.h"

using namespace std;
...
void assign(Expression *expr, Register *reg);
void load(Expression *expr, Register *reg);
...
void assign(Expression *expr, Register *reg) {
    if (expr != nullptr) {
        if (expr->_register != nullptr)
            expr->_register->_node = nullptr;
            
        expr->_register = reg;
    }
    
    if (reg != nullptr) {
        if (reg->_node != nullptr)
            reg->_node->_register = nullptr;
        
        reg->_node = expr;
    
    }
}


...

void load(Expression *expr, Register *reg)
{
    if (reg->_node != expr) {
        if (reg->_node != nullptr) {
            offset -= reg->_node->type().size();
            reg->_node->_offset = offset;
            cout << "\tmovl\t" << reg << ", ";
            cout << offset << "(%ebp)" << endl;
        }
        
        if (expr != nullptr) {
            cout << (expr->type().size() == 1 ? "\tmovsbl\t" : "\tmovl\t");
            cout << expr << ", " << reg << endl;
        }
        
        assign(expr, reg);
    }
}
```

Register.h includes:

```
class Register {
    typedef std::string string;
    string _name;
    string _byte;

public:
    class Expression *_node;

    Register(const string &name, const string &byte = "");
    const string &name(unsigned size = 0) const;
    const string &byte() const;
};

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &ostr, const Register *reg);
```

Comment: Do you use Unicode in your code editor ?

Comment: BTW, C/C++ identifiers are case-sensitive so "Register" is definitely no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing line that creates error and rewriting it, because you probably copied something and pasted it with some illegal unprintable characters.

Comment: I think those unicode chars are part of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration and definition of assign() seems fine. I only guess (...) you might have mismatched "{" somewhere in generator.cpp before the definition (or even in one of the included headers).